# <nav> down the left of the page

Tags: html, css

One of the benefits of HTML 5 are semantic tags like `<header>`, `<nav>` and `<main>`.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to style them so the `<nav>` goes down the left of the page, not without a parent `<div>`, anyhow. It seems to me that such a `<div>` messes up the semantics, and I'm not sure it's technically valid HTML.

```
<header>My Page</header>
<div class="nav-main"> <!-- I don't like this -->
    <nav>
        <a href="/foo.html">Foo</a>
        <a href="/bar.html">Bar</a>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <h1>My Main Content</h1>
        <p>Blah.</p>
    </main>
</div>
<footer>ⓒ Not really copyright</footer>
```

The CSS:

```
div.nav-main {
    display: flex;
}
nav {
    width: 10em;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
}
```

Is there a clean way to do it, without the `<div>`?

I don't think an old-school `float: left` is a solution, because I don't want the `<main>` to wrap around the `<nav>` if it's taller, and I don't want to add arbitrary heights or other hacks. I just want the `<main>` and `<nav>` to both be their natural heights and have consistent widths, and for the `<footer>` to be underneath both.

Otherwise, if somebody can cite assurance that wrapping `<nav>` and `<main>` in a `<div>` is okay, I'll just thank you and move along… although it still doesn't look very elegant to me.

Comment: Have to tried applying `display: block` and `position: relative` (or similar)  to these elements?

Comment: @Johannes: It didn't occur to me, but I just tried removing the `<div>` and applying the properties you suggested to `<nav>` and `<main>`, and the `<nav>` remains on top of the `<main>`. So thanks, but I don't think it'll work; the only way I've ever found to create this kind of column setup is either with flexbox, or a big mess of horrible hacks, which is why I'm using flexbox here.

Comment: You didn't really describe what you want. My comment was just a suggestion that you can style these HTML5 elements any way you want using CSS properties on them. But if you want `nav` and `main` to be flex-items, there is no way around putting a wrapper element (DIV) around them to apply `flex` to that one. As you wrote, these elements are semantic, but they don't have any inherent "automatic CSS" which would style them in any particular way.

Comment: @Johannes: I don't necessarily want them to be flex items; it's just that flexbox is the only way I've found to do what I _do_ want, which I tried to explain in the second-last paragraph. It's pretty much the same setup that a lot of websites have, and not that unlike the navbar on this very StackOverflow page, so I thought it might be possible just with HTML5's semantic tags and CSS3. But it sounds like you're saying it's not, which I suppose answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `display: inline-block` on both and set widths for them that sum up to the page width or a little bit less (using percentage values). That has nothing to do with HTML5, but does not require a wrapper element anyway (if you don't need it for anything else).

Comment: Ah, indeed… if I decide I'm okay with fixed widths, then that will probably work, and I think all the browsers I care about support `calc()` in CSS now anyhow, so 'liquid' widths may be possible, too. (I generally prefer to keep the web versatile and allow users to choose any reasonable size for their browsers.) Cheers.

Comment: you can style nav itself, no height/width but you can add bit of padding to each links under nav. Please see this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vjsqn6ue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a `<div>` is a non-semantic element, so you technically have valid html here. But I understand not wanting divs everywhere. You could potentially put flex on the body, set the width of the header and footer to 100% so they would be on their own line. So it'd be

```
body 
{
 display:flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
}
header, footer
{
 width:100%
}
```

Hopes this helps!

Comment: Ah, yes, I started in that direction, but it didn't occur to me that this is the way to put the header and footer on their own 'lines'. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying too hard to achieve minimalist markup. What you have there is extremely simple compared to almost any website. If it works to have a couple div elements for layout, there's no issue.

The key is that relevant content is contained in your semantic elements, not that you *only* use semantic elements. If you're doing any sort of modern, flexible, responsive layout it can't be avoided.

Comment: Well, yes, I made up a very simple example for the purposes of this question. I wasn't trying to _only_ use semantic elements; I just hadn't found any official word about whether a `<div>` can technically be a parent of a `<main>` and `<nav>`. But I eventually found it in the MDN web docs, and those are good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't found 'official' (W3C) word about whether a `<div>` can be a legal parent for a `<nav>` or `<main>`, but I do trust [Mozilla's web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/). They state that:

- [`<nav>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) can have '[a]ny element that accepts [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content)' as a parent, and
- [`<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)'s parent can be any element '[w]here flow content is expected, but only if it is a [hierarchically correct `main` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#hierarchically-correct-main-element)'.

So in this example, the `<div>` is fine.